Object language, Self Contradictory and Syntax
Following a previous question I asked about Falsum as primitive Symbol of the Object Language of the Propositional Calculus and its Semantic Interpretation, a similar question arises regarding its syntactic interpretation.
The Falsum is a Self Contradictory formula, e.g. "A . (~A)". This definition allows to avoid a reference to Truth and Falsehood.
But, since the Object Language is meaningless, Self Contradictory is an anticipated reference to Syntax. So, isn't Isn't there a problem with this?
Note : Now, I leave the semantical point of view and want to discuss Syntax only. 'Falsum' is e.g. 'A and not A' is a self contradiction, disqualified by syntactic rules (I assume, because of consistency needs). The choice of this primitive Symbol is syntactically minded. Conversely, if I choose to build the system with 'and' and 'not' as only primitive connectors, I avoid any syntactically minded item in the Object Language. Why Logicians didn't avoid an anticipated reference to Syntax in their system (e g. Quine, completeness of the Propositional Calculus).
If the basic connectors are conjunction and negation, nothing in them is a syntactical judgement (neither semantical nor syntactical). If instead the basic are → and F, the concept of contradiction (or falsehood in semantical point of view) is already assumed in the Object Language.

As said previously, a contradiction A and not-A is a formula with a specific form. Thus, the concept is syntactical. Obviously, we have in mind its semantical interpretation, where "and" means conjunction and "not" means negation, and a contradiction is a statement that can never be true, whatever is the state of affairs that A states.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I got it. Syntax doesn't refer to an interpretation but is a grammatical rule of OL. So, despite that OL is meaningless, the connection between Syntax and OL is different from the connection between Semantic and OP.

In regards to your previous question, it's worth noting that the law of explosion (ex contradictione quodlibet) is not required. Another option might be paraconsistent logic: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/

I don't see why you would say that "'Falsum' is 'A and not A' is disqualified by syntactic rules". Every connective can be thought of as having syntactic or proof-theoretic rules and also a semantics. In the case of conjunction, there are rules for introducing and eliminating it:
   A     B                    A ∧ B
   -------   ∧I             --------   ∧E
    A ∧ B                    A    B

And there is a semantics for it. "A ∧ B" is true if and only if "A" is true and "B" is true. Similarly for falsum we have the syntactic rules of proof:
   A    ¬A                     ⊥
  ---------    ⊥I           -------    ⊥E
      ⊥                        A

And the semantics is simply that ⊥ is false in all models. So falsum does not give rise to any additional problem.
In fact, falsum can be understood in different ways, but the effect is pretty much the same. You can think of it:

As a zero-place logical connective in the object language that is always false.

As a placeholder that says, in effect, insert your favourite contradiction here.

As a dead end in a proof procedure: this path in the proof cannot be satisfied so you need to backtrack.


